# To align Outer grid and inner grid equally

Tags: c#, datagridview, grid

I'm using grid inside the grid. My scenario is in the outer grid in a row i have an Expand image as a first column. By clicking this an inner grid will be displayed. I did this and i got the result. But i'm facing allignment issue. Actually i have the same number of columns in both the grids. When i click the expand icon in a row, the inner grid is not alligned properly to the outer grid. 
How to achive this.

The Format i need is like

- Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4----------------Outer Grid
  _   Inner Grid Row1 -----------------------------Inner Grid Row1
      Value1_1    Value1_2    Value1_3------------Inner Grid Row1 values 
      Value2_1    Value2_2    Valuew_3
- Inner Grid Row2
  _       Value1_1    Value1_2    Value1_3
      Value2_1    Value2_2    Valuew_3

[image: Grid Allignment]

How to allign like this.

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the trouble you are facing is that even though you are using two different grids you would like the column widths to line up.  If that's correct you could use the method:

```
DataGridViewColumn.GetPreferredWidth()
```

This method is [explained here on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.getpreferredwidth.aspx).

What you can do is either:

1. Decide which grid is "in charge" of the width.  Then get the preferred width of the column in the appropriate grid.  Finally, set the width of the corresponding column in BOTH grids to the same width.
2. Check the preferred width of the column in BOTH grids and compare them, taking the higher number as your new width.  Then set both column widths to that number.